# Symfony 1.4 Fatal error Class 'myUser' not found

Tags: php, nginx, symfony-1.4

In error log I see:

```
Fatal error: Class 'myUser' not found in /usr/share/nginx/www/services/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_factories.yml.php on line 120
```

What can caouse this problem ?

Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/www/services/web;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        access_log /usr/share/nginx/www/log/access.log;
        error_log  /usr/share/nginx/www/log/error.log;
        server_name server.lap;


        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

}

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

              location ~ ^/(index|frontend|frontend_dev|backend|backend_dev)\.php$ {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to see if there is a myUser.class.php file in the lib folder of your app.  If there isn't create one and in it add:

```
<?php

class myUser extends sfBasicSecurityUser
{
}

?>
```

Or if you are using sfGuardPlugin:

```
<?php

class myUser extends sfGuardSecurityUser
{
}

?>
```

Then clear the cache.